What is the exact meaning of `n_informative` parameter in `sklearn.datasets.make_regression`?
The official documentation to sklearn states that

The output [of sklearn.datasets.make_regression] is generated by applying a (potentially biased) random linear regression model with n_informative nonzero regressors to the previously generated input and some gaussian centered noise with some adjustable scale.

I struggle to understand the exact meaning of these words. What is the mathematical model of "n_informative nonzero regressors"? Does that mean that we generate n_informative coefficients $w_{k}$ of the form $w_{0}+\sum_{k=1}^{\text{n_informative}-1}w_{k}x_{k}$ which we apply with some random noise to n_features random strings to produce the initial data? Do we generate a random n_informative$\times$n_features matrix? How do we generate the y column?
